# Unable to run backup script shipped with Neo4j Enterprise 1.8.2

Tags: neo4j, windows-server-2012

Operating System: Windows 2012
Neo4j Version: 1.8.2 Enterprise

I am having trouble using the Neo4jBackup.bat script to backup the Neo4j server. I am running the following command from an Administrator command prompt:

```
.\Neo4jBackup.bat -full -from single://127.0.0.1 -to E:\Neo4j-Backup
```

When I run this command, I receive the following output and stack trace:

```
Performing full backup from 'single://127.0.0.1'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.newIndexWriter(LuceneDataSource.java:685)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.syncGetIndexSearcher(LuceneDataSource.java:574)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.getIndexSearcher(LuceneDataSource.java:540)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.makeSureAllIndexesAreInstantiated(LuceneDataSource.java:893)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.listStoreFiles(LuceneDataSource.java:833)
    at org.neo4j.com.ServerUtil.rotateLogsAndStreamStoreFiles(ServerUtil.java:129)
    at org.neo4j.backup.BackupImpl.fullBackup(BackupImpl.java:41)
    at org.neo4j.backup.BackupClient$BackupRequestType$1.call(BackupClient.java:73)
    at org.neo4j.backup.BackupClient$BackupRequestType$1.call(BackupClient.java:69)
    at org.neo4j.com.Server$4.run(Server.java:427)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.getCanonicalPath(FSDirectory.java:129)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.<init>(FSDirectory.java:143)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory.<init>(MMapDirectory.java:93)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.open(FSDirectory.java:180)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.open(FSDirectory.java:172)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource$DirectoryGetter$1.getDirectory(LuceneDataSource.java:914)
    at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.newIndexWriter(LuceneDataSource.java:664)
    ... 15 more
```

What am I doing wrong? The Neo4j settings related to backup are set to:

```
online_backup_enabled=true
online_backup_port=6362
```

Your assistance is appreciated. Thank you.

Amir.

Comment: I have not received any solutions to this question. Is there anyone running Neo4j on Windows? If so, have you tried backing up your data using the backup script that ships with Neo4j?

Comment: Did you try something like  `Neo4jBackup.bat -full -from single://127.0.0.1 -to E:\\Neo4j-Backup`

Comment: Yes, I have tried it with E:\\Neo4j-Backup. I have tried also the variation E://Neo4j-Backup. No luck there either.

Comment: I tried running the backup from Mac OSX machine using the command
`./neo4j-backup -full -from single://[machine IP] -to ~/backup-neo4j` and the result is the stacktrace posted originally. I am beginning to believe that the backup script and tool in Neo4j are just broken. Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the name of the directory where you keep the server data? The problem seems to be on the server-side, not the backup-client.

Comment: @RickardÖberg the data files live in a folder with the path E:\NEO4JHOME. I don't see how this path will be an issue. Thoughts?

Comment: Agreed, that should be an ok path. It's a local drive right?

Comment: Yes, it is a local path. Anyway, we implemented a backup system using shadow copies. This is not ideal and it works, for now.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using valid URI syntax for the backup location, like

```
.\Neo4jBackup.bat -full -from single://127.0.0.1 -to /E:/Neo4j-Backup
```

Does that work?

Comment: No, it does not work. I receive the exact same error message. I ran the command you provided precisely. Any other ideas?

Comment: I tried running the backup from Mac OSX machine using the command
`./neo4j-backup -full -from single://[machine IP] -to ~/backup-neo4j` and the result is the stacktrace posted originally. I am beginning to believe that the backup script and tool in Neo4j are just broken. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command like this

```
Neo4jBackup.bat -full -from single://127.0.0.1 -to E:/Neo4j-Backup
```

Comment: I ran the command as you have typed it. The result is the same error message as described originally. Any other ideas?

Comment: Check if you have write access on that folder? and have you tried changing the backup folder location?

Comment: I tried the following from the Administrator command prompt:

- Use the copy command to write data to the backup folder (Success)
- Run the backup command for Neo4j to the backup folder (Fail)
- Create a new directory on another local drive on the server and run the Neo4j backup command (Fail)
- Run the Neo4j backup command on another local drive without first creating the directory (Fail)

Comment: I tried running the backup from Mac OSX machine using the command
`./neo4j-backup -full -from single://[machine IP] -to ~/backup-neo4j` and the result is the stacktrace posted originally. I am beginning to believe that the backup script and tool in Neo4j are just broken. Any thoughts?